# I'm new to programming, is there a shorter way of achieving the same result using something like a case or caseif?

Tags: swift, if-statement, switch-statement, case

I have the code below written in my program, but I was wondering if someone could help me structure in a more summarized way as using 'case' or 'caseif' from other languages.

```
   var imagePressed: UIImageView
    imagePressed = self.redImage

    if color == 1 {

        imagePressed = self.redImage
    }
    if color == 2 {

        imagePressed = self.orangeImage
    }
    if color == 3 {

        imagePressed = self.yellowImage
    }
    if color == 4 {

        imagePressed = self.greenImage
    }

    imagePressed.alpha = 0.5
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to use Dictionary to avoid much code:

```
let images = [1 : redImage, 2 : orangeImage, 3: yellowImage, 4: greenImage]
if let image = images[color] {
    imagePressed = image
}
```

Also consider replacing hardcoded numbers with a enum for color e.g.:

```
enum Color {
    case red
    case orange
...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift also provides the `switch` statement.
You could simply type

```
var imagePressed: UIImageView

switch color {
    case 1: imagePressed = self.redImage
    case 2: imagePressed = self.orangeImage
    case 3: imagePressed = self.yellowImage
    case 4: imagePressed = self.greenImage
    default: // provide any default value
}
```

Note that Swift `switch` statement has no implicit fallthrough. That mean, if any case is matching, the code flow breaks there.
Use comma-separated conditions to match multiple cases.

I recommend to read the `switch` statement in their language guide:
https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ControlFlow.html#ID129

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is quite inefficient anyway because the code checks always all conditions even if color is 1.

A better form is `if - else if`

```
var imagePressed : UIImageView
imagePressed = self.redImage
if color == 1 {
    imagePressed = self.redImage
} else if color == 2 {
    imagePressed = self.orangeImage
} else if color == 3 {
    imagePressed = self.yellowImage
} else if color == 4 {
    imagePressed = self.greenImage
}
imagePressed.alpha = 0.5
```

In this particular case I recommend to use a `switch` statement and drop the extra variable

```
switch color {
    case 1: self.redImage.alpha = 0.5
    case 2: self.orangeImage.alpha = 0.5
    case 3: self.yellowImage.alpha = 0.5
    case 4: self.greenImage.alpha = 0.5
    default: break
}
```